# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid caused by delete_all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In our rails 3.1.4 app, the excessive number of entries in system log will be deleted with a method in sys_log model:

```
  def self.trim_log(num_entry)
    if SysLog.count > num_entry      
      SysLog.where("log_date < #{SysLog.all[num_entry -1].log_date}").delete_all
    end
  end
```

Here the num_entry is the log entry we want to keep. Any entry before that entry will be deleted. However the delete_all causes following error in rspec:

```
 ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mSysLog.trim_log(1)←[0m
 ←[31mActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:←[0m
   ←[31mSQLite3::SQLException: near "03": syntax error: DELETE FROM "sys_logs" WHERE (log_date < 2012-06-10 03:43:21 UTC)←[0m
```

The error is the same in rails console. The database is sqlite3 in our development. log_date is a datetime. What's wrong with our code? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SysLog.where("log_date < ?", SysLog.all[num_entry -1].log_date).delete_all
```

to properly quote your date.

But consider revision. I guess you can fetch your num_entry-1'th element this way:

```
SysLog.offset(num_entry-1).first
```

which is MUCH MORE efficient then fetching all of them.